# Atomicity of states and output

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

If the code in my ProcessElement method both modifies one (or more) state variable and also outputs some results, do I have a guarantee in Dataflow on the atomicity of this operation?

Let's clarify my question with an example of code (take from https://beam.apache.org/blog/stateful-processing/ ):

```
  @ProcessElement
  public void processElement(
      ProcessContext context,
      @StateId("index") ValueState<Integer> index) {
    int current = firstNonNull(index.read(), 0);
    context.output(KV.of(current, context.element()));
    index.write(current+1);
  }
```

If the Dataflow worker suddenly dies, is there a risk that the context.output() has been executed/checkpointed, but the "index" state variable has not been accordingly updated?

Another doubt I have is:
I know that a ParDo can execute twice on the same input record (due to retry or speculative execution) and Dataflow guarantees "exactly once" of the output by using some deduplication based on an ID attached to each output record.
However, do I also get some "exactly once" guarantee for some "non idempotent" operations on a state like the above "current+1" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dataflow guarantees that state mutations and outputs are committed atomically, that is, either both or neither take affect. (Specifically, all states and outputs between StartBundle and EndBundle are so tied together.) If a record needs to be retried, the original state will be used.

Comment: Thanks! Is there any documentation of Google that describes this? I have been searching in the Beam doc and I am also reading the very good "Streaming System" Oreilly book but I have failed to find some details on this atomicity.

Comment: This atomicity is part of the model, but I am unable to find good documentation on that. Perhaps I should update https://beam.apache.org/documentation/runtime/model/